# Another word for "large in numbers"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word denoting the fact that something is very large in numbers, something like *proliferated* but not quite?

> While certainly not as [**proliferated**] as B2C apps, business to business...

Comment: *numerous*, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I clicked 'Ask Question' the answer occurred to me: `abundant` is the word I was looking for.

> While certainly not as abundant as B2C apps, business to business...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[legion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/legion)* (meaning 6) would fit the bill. This usage has a slightly disapproving tone, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Multitude.

In the Bible, Joel 3:14:

Multitudes, multitudes in the valley of decision! For the day of the LORD is near in the valley of decision.

Multitudinous, when used as adjective.

Multitude, like "many", is for countable quantities.

Magnitude, like "much", is used for uncountable quantities.

Magnitude is from Latin magna - great.

Answer (score 0):

galore
Galore' is placed after the word that it modifies.